# Determine whether it is convergent or divergent: $\int_{-1}^0 {\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

So I was evaluating this improper integral, and found the antiderivative to be $e^{1/x}(1-\frac{1}{x})$. How would I evaluate it from $0$ to $-1$? In other words, what would $\frac{1}{0}$ be?
$$\int_{-1}^0 {\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^3}}dx$$

I know there is a similar post to this question: [Improper Integral of $\int_{-1}^0 \frac{e^\frac{1}{x}}{x^3}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622235/improper-integral-of-int-10-frace-frac1xx3dx)

I've read it, but it doesn't really help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the $0$ in “ $\dfrac10$ ” is slightly negative, so we are actually dealing with

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{1/x}\bigg(1-\frac1x\bigg)$, where the first part goes towards $e^{-\infty}=0$, and the latter

towards $\infty$. Applying l'Hopital, the two quantities balance each other out, and

the limit is finite.

Comment: @ Lucian How do you know it's slightly negative and not positive? Or is there two situations?

Comment: @liya77: Because you are integrating on $(-1,0)$, as opposed to, say, $(0,1)$, so the upper integration limit tends to $0$ from below or from the left.