# Value of the Improper Integral $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{T/x}}{x^S}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have the following function defined piecewise continuous with $S,T\in\mathbb{R} > 0$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{e^{T/u}}{u^S} & x < 0 \\
      0 & x \geq 0 
   \end{cases}
$$

and I want to normalize this function to integrate to $1$. This creates a particularly tricky integral though that I have never seen before and I was wondering if anyone knew about how to get the value in terms of $S,T$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{T/x}}{x^S}dx
$$

I've tried the standard methods, but this appears harder then I'm used to, if anyone has some insight!

Comment: Related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622235/improper-integral-of-int-10-frace-frac1xx3dx) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183236/determine-whether-it-is-convergent-or-divergent-int-10-frace1-xx).

Comment: Thats what I initially thought, but in both of those cases we had that $T, S$ were integers $1,3$ respectively. How can this generalize to members of $\mathbb{R}$. It kinda looks like a gamma integral but the exponents do not match properly

Comment: You may want to look into the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral is very close to the integral definition of the gamma function which is
$$\Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} e^{-x} dx$$

First use the substitution $u = \frac{1}{x} , -\frac{1}{u^2} du = dx$ to get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{T/x}}{x^s} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{Tu} u^{s-2} du$$

(As we are approaching 0 from the left, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} = -\infty$)

Next use the substitution $v = -Tu, \frac{-dv}{T} = du$ to get

$$(-1)^s T^{1-s} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-v} v^{s-2} dv = (-1)^s T^{1-s} \Gamma(s-1)$$

Comment: This makes sense, but it appears that this integral could provide both a complex, and a negative result, when the function as definied is real and positive over the entire domain

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an example of the incomplete gamma function.

The (upper) incomplete gamma function is defined as $\Gamma(s,x) = \int_x^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t} dt$

Now, $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{e^{T/x}}{x^S} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{T/x}}{x^S}dx - \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{T/x}}{x^S}dx$

You should now be able to bring the terms in the standard form to use the incomplete gamma function using variable substitution