# Finding the limit of $\frac {e^{-1/x^2}}{x^{100}}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Finding the limit of: $$\frac {e^{-1/x^2}}{x^{100}}$$ as $x \rightarrow 0$

**My answer is:**

1- I can not apply L`hopital rule because the limit will still be 0/0 because the numerator will still be exponential and the power of the denominator is increasing .... am I correct?

2- I will solve it by taking into account the exponential growth relative to the polynomial growth and knowing that the exponential growth is much faster than the polynomial growth then the exponential term is the dominant term and the limit will be zero .... am I correct ? .... and will my answer deserve a full credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed we can also apply l’Hopital several times or as an alternative we have that

$$\frac {e^{-1/x^2}}{x^{100}}=\frac {1}{x^{100}e^{1/x^2}}\to 0$$

indeed for all $y>0$ and $n$ eventually

$$e^y\ge y^n \implies e^{1/x^2}\ge \frac1{x^{102}}$$

and thus

$$\frac{1}{x^{100}e^{1/x^2}}\le \frac{1}{x^{100}\frac1{x^{102}}}=x^2\to 0$$

Refer also to the related

- [The Rapidity of the Exponential Function Towards Infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55247/505767)

Comment: Could you describe more your forth line ....... your $y = -1/x^2$ ?  and n .... what?

Comment: For any $y>0$ and exponent $n>0$ we have that eventually $e^y\ge y^n$, now take $y=1/x^2$ and $n=51$ to obtain the RHS.

Comment: @hopefully Since the exponential growth is greater than any polynomial growth (the fact is obviuosly true as an extension also for $n$ real).

Comment: @hopefully If we assume the result as a given the limit follows immediately otherwise we need to prove that.

Comment: are you assuming that $x$ is positive?

Comment: @hopefully Since in that case $\frac {e^{-1/x^2}}{x^{100}}=\frac {e^{-1/x^2}}{{(x^2)}^{50}}$ we can wlog assume $x>0$. Note indeed that I've ssumed $y=1/x^2 >0$ which is always true for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Once we provethat eventually $e^y\ge y^n$ for any $y>0$ and $n>0$ the result follows.

Comment: @hopefully I've added a reference for that proof.

Answer (score 4):

You should notice that this boils down to the limits $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log x} {x} =0\text{ or }\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x} {e^x} =0$$ You can use L'Hospital's Rule to prove the above limits. There are proofs based on simpler tools like Squeeze Theorem.

For the current question just put  $1/x^2=t$ to get $$\lim_{t\to \infty }\frac{t^{50}}{e^t}$$ Further if we put $t=50u$ then the above limit gets transformed into $$\lim_{u\to\infty}50^{50} \left(\frac{u}{e^u}\right)^{50}$$ and this equals $50^{50}\cdot 0^{50}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Set $1/x^2=y$ to find $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^{100}}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\dfrac{y^{50}}{e^y}$$

Now apply L'Hospital as the ratio is of the from $\dfrac\infty\infty$

Comment: I think it will take a huge number of times of applying l`hopital also .... am I correct?.....what about my second question ?

Comment: @hopefully, Yes you can take $50$th derivative or  expand $e^y$

Comment: @hopefully You are right with your your second question. In this cases exponential functions always "win" against polinomial functions and those always "win" again logarythmic functions. If you will get full credit depends on your corrector and how detailed you explain your argument (and why you are allowed to use it).